# how to know job status in oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle10g

i created one job in oracle10g

my table name  is  name i.e

```
create table name(name varchar2(10))
```

and i created one procedure with the name: insertnames to insert values into name table

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job
(
job_name => 'insertnames'
job_type => 'stored_procedure',
job_action => 'insertnames(spname)'
start_date => sysdate,
enabled => true,
auto_drop => false
);
end;
```

the above job is executed successfully but how can i know whether this job is running fine or not?

Answer (score 3):

to see what is running, use the view: `USER_SCHEDULER_RUNNING_JOBS`

and to see if a job was successful use: `USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG`/`USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS`

(or use the ALL_/DBA_ versions of the views as applicable)

Answer (score 0):

There is a series of system views beginning with USER/ALL/DBA_SCHEDULER_, such as ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS or ALL_SCHEDULER_RUNNING_JOBS, documented here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2038.htm.